# JPA ManyToOne relationship help needed

Tags: java, many-to-one

I am a noob at JPA and need some help please.

I have a parent which references a child entity by design and I would like to persist the parent entity without the child entity being persisted as it already exists on the DB.

With the code below, it throws out a "detached entity passed to persist" exception and I am assuming that it is doing this because it is trying to persist an entry that already exists.

### Parent Entity

```
public class Channels implements Serializable
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID")
String id;

@Column(name = "name")
String name;

@Column(name = "shortCode")
String shortCode;

@Column(name = "loggerName")
String loggerName;

@Column(name = "SAFName")
String safName;

@Column(name = "Period")
int period;

@Column(name = "defaultErrorCode")
String defaultErrorCode;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "keySource", referencedColumnName = "source")
KeyGroup keySource; ///Child
```

### Child entity

```
public class KeyGroup implements java.io.Serializable
{
@Id
@Column(name = "source")
String source;

@Column(name = "parentKey")
private String parentKey;

@Column(name = "parentKeyCheckValue")
private String parentKeyCheckValue;

@Column(name = "parentKeyParity")
private String parentKeyParity;

@Column(name = "childKey")
private String childKey;

@Column(name = "childKeyCheckValue")
private String childKeyCheckValue;
```

### Populate the class

```
Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form")
{
   @Override
   public void onSubmit()
   {
     Channels channels = new Channels();
     KeyGroup keyGroup = keyGroupServiceProvider.getKeyGroup(keySource.getModelObject().getSource());

     channels.setId(id.getModelObject());
     channels.setName(channelName.getModelObject());
     channels.setShortCode(channelShortCode.getModelObject());
     channels.setLoggerName(loggerName.getModelObject());
     channels.setSafName(SAFName.getModelObject());
     channels.setPeriod(Integer.parseInt(period.getModelObject()));
     channels.setDefaultErrorCode(defaultErrorCode.getModelObject());


     try
     {
        channelServiceProvider.addChannel(channels, keyGroup);
        info("done");
     }
```

### The EJB that persists

```
EntityManager entityManager;
```

.
.
.
.

```
public void addChannel(Channels channels, KeyGroup keyGroup)
{
    try
    {
        channels.setKeySource(keyGroup);
        entityManager.persist(channels);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks in advance guys